# How to add your topic to the list of topics customtkinter

Tags: customtkinter

Need help I can't figure out how to add my topic to the topics list and still have it applied.

How to add your theme in this piece of code? By default there is white black and system black.

`self.appearance_mode_menu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.navigation_frame, values=["Light", "Dark", "System"], command=self.change_appearance_mode_event) self.appearance_mode_menu.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="s")`

I tried uploading a json file and using it but it didn't work for me.